# As a careers site user I would like to favorite a company so that when I am actively searching for a job I don't forget about them

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Title sums it up:

> As a careers site user
>
> I would like to favorite a company
>
> So that when I am actively searching for a job I don't forget about them

Comment: well, that was brief ;-)  seems reasonable

Comment: That's why I love user stories :)